# Network Adapter to make PC 802.11ad compatible

Tags: wifi, desktop, networking

I am impressed with the performance of the TP-Link AD7200 Wireless Router. But I am also aware that the 802.11ad ecosystem is still growing. There are not too many devices that support this band range/technology natively. Typically, one may buy a network adapter card that plugs in via usb or PCIe. However, when browsing different online sites, I found no network adapters that support 802.11ad.

Am I just really bad at searching or are there really no network adapters for 802.11ad yet? If the latter is true, I would find that surprising because it's halfway into 2017, and this ecosystem is **still** in its infancy?

My end goal is to put a 802.11ad network adapter into my desktop PC. I'm not sure what needs to be compatible for such a configuration, so here is some (hopefully) relevant information:

- use scenario: open floor-plan (no walls)
- available pcie slots: 1
- available usb slots: 5
- cpu: 4790k
- motherboard: z97x-gaming 3

Answer (score 1):

This [link](https://www.google.com/amp/s/arstechnica.com/gadgets/2016/12/802-11ad-wifi-guide-review/%3Famp%3D1) agrees with you:

> These high prices really hit home when you consider which devices are able connect to this router via 802.11ad, which, at the time of writing, were absolutely none. Just about the only product that has even been announced so far is a middle-of-the-road Acer laptop that you can't yet buy anywhere, while there are no PC card adapters, phones, or tablets yet featuring the technology. We strongly suspect it'll be at least another six months before the situation changes.

That was six months ago, but the article even suggests it’s possible nothing will be available yet. I’d just keep crossing your fingers and waiting.

The only products I found were [this](https://m.newegg.com/products/9SIABP54VU7548) and [this](https://m.newegg.com/products/9SIABP55DM1726), but I don’t think they match what you are looking for.

Comment: Those are both M.2 cards.  There are PCIe to M.2 adapters, but virtually all of them have the "M" key used by NVMe drives rather than the "A" key that those have.